# How do I join a chatroom in Skype?

Tags: skype

I'm unable to find the option to join a chatroom in Skype. I've downloaded the latest .deb and it still doensn't show the option to join a chatroom anywhere! I'm on Linux Mint 17.2. Does skype require Java because I've uninstalled it.

Comment: No....you shouldn't need java.